# CSS ISSUE FOR IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

Here the link - http://indivar.us/StackOverFlow/PTCNews/Website/

Hi

Please find the link above. The block that shows "**World and National**" are not float to left in IE8, but works in other browsers very well.

Is there is any deficiency in my css code (ie8.css) or whatever, I could not found the right way ?  Can you please let me know how it goes to float left as in IE9 or other browsers.

Thanks
B.

Answer (score 2):

remove the width for **`ul.outside-punjab`** class then it will be working fine

Answer (score 2):

just remove width from class `UL.outside-punjab` in ie8.css